# What is the meaning of Judge warning words to Lawyer?

Tags: meaning

Situation: Lawyer showed Johnson's family photos who died in plane crash to defendant, Johnson, who got razed upon seeing the photos. Case is filed by family of Johnson's wife on Johnson. Later, Judge called Lawyer to his chamber & warned him.

> First off, you ever pull crap like that in my court again. **I will have
>   hardened inmates using you as a dress-up doll**.

Comment: We say that the case was filed *against* Johnson, not "on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Judge warning the lawyer that if he ever performs  a similar action in his courtroom he will find the lawyer in contempt of court and have him arrested.

He would then be taken to jail, where the other inmates lack female company and will treat the lawyer as a substitute for that company.